# Spring.Data.CannotGetAdoConnectionException : Could not get ADO.NET connection

Tags: c#, spring, unit-testing, nunit

We have a bunch of unit tests running on the build server using this command line:

> mkdir "%WORKSPACE%\Results" del /Q "%WORKSPACE%\Results*.*"
>
> NCover Run --project="%JOB_NAME%" --buildId="%JOB_NAME%
>
> ## %BUILD_NUMBER% V%THE_VERSION%" -- %nunit_exe% Output\XYZLibTests\Product.XYZLib.Tests.dll /exclude:Performance
>
> /noshadow /xml=Results\XYZLib-TestResults.xml

The tests dll is a c# class library, .NET V4.5, and NUnit is NUnit 2.6.4.
We use Spring.Net, and the Context.xml file for the tests dll is:

```
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net"
         xmlns:db="http://www.springframework.net/database"
         xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.net/tx">
  <import resource="assembly://Product.Core.SqlServer/Product.Core.Config/Context.xml"/>
  <import resource="assembly://Product.ImportLib/Product.Import.Config/Context.xml"/>
  <db:provider id="dbProvider" provider="SqlServer-2.0"
               connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DBDataFile.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
  <object id="transactionManager" type="Spring.Data.Core.AdoPlatformTransactionManager, Spring.Data">
    <property name="DbProvider" ref="dbProvider"/>
  </object>
  <object name="Logger" type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.LogFactoryObject, Spring.Core">
    <property name="logName" value="UnitTestLogger"/>
  </object>
  <object id="adoTemplate" type="Spring.Data.Core.AdoTemplate, Spring.Data">
    <property name="CommandTimeout" value="240"/>
    <property name="DbProvider" ref="dbProvider"/>
    <property name="DataReaderWrapperType" value="Spring.Data.Support.NullMappingDataReader, Spring.Data"/>
  </object>
</objects>
```

The test classes look like this:

```
public class ComponentDaoTest
{
        [TestFixtureSetUp]
        public void FixtureSetup()
        {
            this.ComponentDao = Context.GetObject<ComponentDao>();
        }
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            this.ComponentDao.Truncate(); <--cleans localdb attached
        }
//various tests to insert and select from localdb attached
        [TearDown]
        public void Complete()
        {
            this.ComponentDao.Truncate();<--cleans localdb attached
        }
}
```

The ComponentDao is what is being tested, and it is defined in a different assembly:

```
 <object id="ComponentDao" type="Product.Core.SqlServer.ComponentDao, Product.Core.SqlServer">
    <property name="AdoTemplate" ref="adoTemplate"/>
  </object>
```

Its class definition is:

```
public class ComponentDao : AdoDaoSupport, IComponentDao
```

IComponentDao is a product-specific interface that not implement any known interfaces such as IDisposable.

The problem is, these unit tests ran for a while, but we would see that once in a while we would get the following exception for all of them (in this case for FindAllTest):

```
TearDown Error : Product.CoreLib.Tests.Data.ComponentDaoTest.FindAllTest
16:16:20    SetUp : Spring.Data.CannotGetAdoConnectionException : Could not get ADO.NET connection.
16:16:20   ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=15370; handshake=55; 
16:16:20   ----> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : The wait operation timed out
16:16:20 TearDown : Spring.Data.CannotGetAdoConnectionException : Could not get ADO.NET connection.
16:16:20   ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=15370; handshake=55; 
16:16:20   ----> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : The wait operation timed out
16:16:20    at Spring.Data.Support.ConnectionUtils.GetConnectionTxPair(IDbProvider provider)
16:16:20    at Spring.Data.Core.AdoAccessor.GetConnectionTxPair(IDbProvider provider)
16:16:20    at Spring.Data.Core.AdoTemplate.Execute(ICommandCallback action)
16:16:20    at Spring.Data.Core.AdoTemplate.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType cmdType, String cmdText)
16:16:20    at Product.Core.SqlServer.ComponentDao.Truncate() in c:\Jenkins\Workspace\...\CoreLib\SqlServer\ComponentDao.cs:line 133
16:16:20    at Product.CoreLib.Tests.Data.ComponentDaoTest.Setup() in c:\Jenkins\Workspace\...\CoreLib.Tests\Data\ComponentDaoTest.cs:line 39
16:16:20 --SqlException
16:16:20    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
16:16:20    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
16:16:20    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
16:16:20    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
16:16:20    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
16:16:20    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
16:16:20    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
16:16:20    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
16:16:20    at Spring.Data.Support.ConnectionUtils.DoGetConnection(IDbProvider provider)
16:16:20    at Spring.Data.Support.ConnectionUtils.GetConnectionTxPair(IDbProvider provider)
16:16:20 --Win32Exception
16:16:20 
16:16:20 --TearDown
16:16:20    at Spring.Data.Support.ConnectionUtils.GetConnectionTxPair(IDbProvider provider)
16:16:20    at Spring.Data.Core.AdoAccessor.GetConnectionTxPair(IDbProvider provider)
16:16:20    at Spring.Data.Core.AdoTemplate.Execute(ICommandCallback action)
16:16:20    at Spring.Data.Core.AdoTemplate.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType cmdType, String cmdText)
16:16:20    at Product.Core.SqlServer.ComponentDao.Truncate() in c:\Jenkins\Workspace\...\CoreLib\SqlServer\ComponentDao.cs:line 133
16:16:20    at Product.CoreLib.Tests.Data.ComponentDaoTest.Complete() in c:\Jenkins\Workspace\...\CoreLib.Tests\Data\ComponentDaoTest.cs:line 48
16:16:20 --SqlException
16:16:20    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
16:16:20    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
16:16:20    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
16:16:20    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
16:16:20    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
16:16:20    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
16:16:20    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
16:16:20    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
16:16:20    at Spring.Data.Support.ConnectionUtils.DoGetConnection(IDbProvider provider)
16:16:20    at Spring.Data.Support.ConnectionUtils.GetConnectionTxPair(IDbProvider provider)
16:16:20 --Win32Exception
```

I guess all the tests are using the same Ado Connection to the same localdb database configured in the Context.xml, but the thing is, sometimes they all run without error. These tests have not been changed in a long time, so the on and off failure is what is puzzling us.